# mssql-server-windows-express Docker container stops immediately

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm trying to run SQL Server Express in a Docker container.

When I run `docker container run -d -P my-db:v1` it immediately stops.

The Docker file:

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express

ENV ACCEPT_EULA="Y" `
    DATA_PATH="C:\data" `
    sa_password="mypw"

VOLUME ${DATA_PATH}
WORKDIR C:\folder1
```

When I remove the `WORKDIR` line at the end, the container keeps running.

When including the `WORKDIR` line and running the container, Docker Desktop shows:

```
.\start : The term '.\start' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or

if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:76

+ ... e = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; .\start -sa_pas ...

+ ~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (.\start:String) [], ParentConta

insErrorRecordException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When I inspect the container, it shows the startup command which looks ok:

```json
"Path": "powershell",
        "Args": [
            "-Command",
            "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';",
            ".\\start -sa_password $env:sa_password -ACCEPT_EULA $env:ACCEPT_EULA -attach_dbs \\\"$env:attach_dbs\\\" -Verbose"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CMD .\start`  requires the `start.ps1` script to be in the `WORKDIR` directory. The source image has `WORKDIR` set to the root directory (C:) and the script is in that directory (C:\Start.ps1).

Now that you've changed `WORKDIR` to C:\folder1), you need either specify a new CMD in the docker file or override the value at run time. Dockerfile example:

```
CMD C:\start.ps1 -sa_password $env:sa_password -attach_dbs \"$env:attach_dbs\" -Verbose
```